# Selecting rows with date between start and end date

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a `timestampz` column in postgresql table and I wish to retrieve entries lying within a specific time frame

I tried using

```
SELECT * FROM table where date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-05'
```

But the above query fails to retrieve some rows that fall within the specified date, so I tried something like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-01-05 23:59:59'
```

This works fine, but Is there a better way to active this?

Comment: Does "date >= startdate AND date <= enddate" return your rows?

Comment: yes, this works, provided I provide the HH:MM:SS with it

Comment: Wait, you have a column of type `timestamptz` named `date`?  That has the potential to be as confusing as a `numeric` column named `integer`.

Answer (score 5):

You can try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
where date::DATE BETWEEN '2012-01-01'::DATE AND '2012-01-05'::DATE
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/8561a/6/0)

Comment: Are you sure? I edited the post, there is link to sql fiddle, for me it works, can you show us your examples dates  ?

Answer (score 5):

Not much better but cleaner i think.

```
select *
from table
where 
    date >= '2012-01-01' 
    and 
    date < '2012-01-05'::date + 1
```

It will cover up to '2012-01-05 23:59:59.999999'

Comment: On days other than the 5th of January, it will even cover leap seconds (23:59:60.999999) :-).